# Can't access open cart Admin from iphone

Tags: iphone, opencart

I have installed opencart on my server and everything seems to be working fine except for the fact that I can't access the admin dashboard through my iphone. It works fine on my PC, on a Mac, and on an android Phone like a Galaxy note 4.

I can't seem to find any information on this. It doesn't generate any errors. the only thing it does is reload the admin sign in screen. If the password is incorrect it displays the error message but if the username and password are correct it doesn't go in.

Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Comment: Have you clear cookies in iPhone's browser? Which version of Opencart are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 1.5.6.3 and I've already cleared everything on the iPhone, still nothing.

Comment: Have you checked for any rules in your **.htaccess** file that might cause this?

Comment: I've never editted the .htaccess file. so i don't think that's it.

Comment: I've just installed a fresh new open cart and that one works fine. so I know it's something in the code of the old one. it's not the server, not the iphones and not the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename temporarly htaccess file then check..

Comment: same thing. doesn't access from iphone only

Comment: please check to another mobile ..instead i phone ..it will be open or not

Comment: your store is on live?

Comment: yes, it works fine with an android phone. it's just iphones that it doesn't work with.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try to search for 'Mobile_Detect' in your code and see if there is any code to check for Iphone around this. Mobile_Detect is a library to detect your device type. It might be happening due to this.

Comment: where is that Mobile_detect file? I've tried to look for it and even online but i can't seem to find it. it is part of all open carts right off the gate?